# Nautilus unable to find default domain ontology rule

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, 18.10, tracker

When trying to open the file manager, nautilus, it doesn't show up, and I wanted to know what's wrong. I opened it from the terminal and it showed this error message.

```
bash: /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh: No such file or   
directory   
nautmsi@MSI:~$ nautilus

(nautilus:25237): Tracker-ERROR **: 14:19:57.123: Unable to find default domain  
ontology rule /usr/share/tracker/domain-ontologies/default.rule  
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
msi@MSI:~$
```

I tried:

- Reinstalling
- Disabling themes (as this problem happened after)
- Searching a lot, hours, but nothing worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of searching, I decided to take the message literally,I tried searching for an app called tracker and actually, `sudo apt install tracker` fixed it!

Comment: [Bug #908800 in nautilus](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=908800) has been fixed in the
Git repository and is awaiting an upload. You can check the diff of the fix at: https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/nautilus/commit/852c9614e51b0746fa3e5fe3d9bd4217091d17e7

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 , nautilus was working very well and suddenly after 5 or 6 days that happened, I guess I updated without noticing that nautilus has an update, thanks anyway

Comment: Or maybe a nautilus update for Ubuntu hasn't been released yet.

Comment: idk tbh, It just happened out of the blue and I started to search without even knowing the reason. It's fixed anyway